# Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'FIRMessaging

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'FIRMessaging** 
I am trying to run my ionic project on a ios platform from Xcode.
[image: Xcode error]

Has anyone ever encountered this type of error on cordova.

I have installed plugin: **cordova fmc** for cloud messaging

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm
```

I have even downgraded from :

```
   "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.7.0",
```

to

```
 "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.0.0",
```

**no success**

Comment: Were you able to get this sorted out? If you were could you share it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the `DerivedData` of my project and also `ModuleCache.noindex` then removing and adding the plarform fixes the problem for me